# How can I grant access to my root site in SharePoint online?

Tags: permissions, site-collection

I've made some custom security groups in SharePoint online at site colelction level and that security is inherited across all my sub-sites.  The issue I have is that my site collection root site is the homepage and yet, despite adding a "Readers" group to it's security no one can access it, they just get a Access Denied message with an option to request access.

[image]

As it's SharePoint online, everyone uses an office 365 account.  They can access all the subsites without problems just not the root site.

The root site has a security group called "Readers" which has "Everybody" in it and has it's permissions set to "Read".

From the site root homepage I goto the cog then `Site Settings` and then `Site Permissions` under `Users and Permissions` I see the following list:

[image]

This is the groups that I made.  In the readers group there is `Everyone` but that doesn't seem to help.  I noticed this `Limited Access` screen which shows me this:
[image]

I've blurred out a couple of individuals names but would this be having an effect?  I'll be honest I'm not even sure how `Limited Access` came to be.  There is one sub-site that has no inheritance because of the people who need to access it.

All we are looking for is 5 groups each with varying levels of permissions, set at site collection level and inherited down.

How can I allow the root site to be read only for the users or is my approach totally wrong?

**Update**
I can access all the site pages of the root site just not the homepage.  The homepage uses a custom master and page layout, has some scripts that run and also webparts.  Yes the scripts have been allowed in settings for everyone.

Comment: What permissions does your "Readers" group have? And did you add "Everyone" to that group?

Comment: Yes "Everyone" is part of the "Readers" group.  Readers group permissions level is set to "Read".  Should it be something else for this area?

Comment: If you check permissions for any user that isn't you, does it say they are receiving Read permissions from the Readers group?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so after much messing around I found the problem.  Looking at the masterpage I checked who it was shared with.  It then said that the masterpage inherited it's permissions from `Master Page Gallery`, I clicked on `Manage Parent` and then added my `Readers` group to that area and boom, it works.

Answer (score 0):

do you have broken permissions in your site collection? 
are you a site collection administrator or just a full control user?

check the permissions of the site collection home page and verify it is inheriting permissions from the site and does not have unique permissions

Comment: Please see my update :)